# A tough problem on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb C$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is an arbitrary operator operating on $V$. Then $T$ is diagonalizable iff $V=\operatorname{null} (T-\lambda I)\oplus \operatorname{range} (T-\lambda I)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb C$.

The first implication is obvious. It is well known that for any operator $T$, $V=\operatorname{null} T \oplus \operatorname{range} T$, so one implication immedaitely follows.

For the secodn implication, i dont know where to start any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $T$. For each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $V_k$ be the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_k$. Then $T(V_k)\subset V_k$ and there is some basis $B_k=\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ of $V_k$ such that the matrix of $T|_{V_k}$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_k&\eta_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&\lambda_k&\eta_2&0&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&\lambda_k\end{bmatrix},$$where each $\eta_l$ is either $0$ or $1$. If $T$ is not diagonalizable, there is at least one $k$ such that some $\eta_l$ is $1$. Suppose, for intance, that $\eta_1=1$. Then $v_1\in\operatorname{null}(T-\lambda_k\operatorname{Id})\cap\operatorname{range}(T-\lambda_k\operatorname{Id})$.

Comment: Can you olease explain the proof more simply. I am not getting it fully

Comment: Can you please tell me where are you having problems?

Comment: Like, what are the $v_k$'s mentioned in $T(v_k) \subset V_k$?

Comment: Also why is the matrix like that?

Comment: The expression $T(v_k)\subset V_k$ was due to a typo. What I meant was $T(V_k)\subset V_k$. And to see why there is such a matrix, just take a Jordan normal form of $T$.

Comment: thank you a lot, but any other way except jordan form? We havent been taught that et

Answer (score 0):

Use Jordan canonical form of the $T$.
Start with letting $T$ is not diagonalisable. Then $T$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ which has a jordan block of size atleast $2$. Show that for that eigenvalue $\lambda$, $V=\operatorname{Null}(T-\lambda I)\oplus\operatorname{Range}(T-\lambda I)$ doesn't hold.